# How to remember which is lower/upper semicontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, mnemonic, semicontinuous-functions

There are several ways in which continuity can be formulated as two conditions - in a way such that one of them is [lower semicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) and the other one is upper semicontinuity. (See below for examples.)

What is a good way to remember which is which? Is there a natural way looking at this which tells me that this one should be called *lower* and the other one *upper* semicontinuity?

If there is some good way to remember several of the conditions at the same time, even better. Or is a better strategy simply to remember some typical example of lower/uppser semicontinuos function - and when in doubt, simply to check which of the two parts holds for this function?

---

Let us work with a function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. (Although all of this can be easily generalized to the case when domain is arbitrary topological space.)

Here are conditions which are equivalent to continuity of $f$ and I also rewrote them into two conditions (with lower semicontinuity on the left)

- The function $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for $|y-x|<\delta$ we have $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$, i.e., $$f(x)-\varepsilon< f(y) \qquad\text{and}\qquad f(y)<f(x)+\varepsilon.$$
- The function $f$ is continuous at $x$ if $\lim\limits_{t\to x} f(t)=f(x)$, i.e.,
  $$f(x) \le \liminf_{t\to x} f(t) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \limsup_{t\to x} f(t)\le f(x).$$
- The function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ if for any $a<b$ the set $f^{-1}(a,b)=\{x\in\mathbb R; a<f(x)<b\}$ is open, i.e., both
  $$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\{x\in\mathbb R; a<f(x)\} \qquad\text{and}\qquad f^{-1}(\infty,b)=\{x\in\mathbb R; f(x)<b\}$$
  are open.

Comment: I can’t think of anything more natural than associating the $...f(x)-\epsilon <f(y)$ with *lower* and the other inequality with *upper*...